# If I own the patent to A+B+C, and later A+B is granted a patent, can I still manufacture A+B+C

Tags: patents

If I manufacture `A+B+C`, then I would be infringing upon `A+B`, no?

Comment: How could the patent to A+B not be invalid due to prior art?

Comment: Your example lacks enough coherent detail for a reasonable answer.  Please provide a specific example.

Comment: It seems as though you are indicating that "A+B" is a subset of "A+B+C".  If that's the case then "A+B" could not be patented by someone else since it's obviously already patented.  If someone were to be granted such a patent, then you could easily challenge it.  For example, if I patent a pencil as consisting of a wood body, a graphite lead, a rubber eraser, with a metal barrel connecting it together, a new patent application for a wood body with a graphite lead core should be rejected since it's nothing but a subset of a previously patented device.

Comment: A+B turns out to be a better solution than A+B+C. C turns out to be superfluous complexity.

Comment: Or is this running into the first-to-file vs first-to-invent problem?

Comment: @BigCatPublicSafetyAct it's a better solution, but it's not a new invention.  It's just a new way of using an existing invention after removing one of its parts.  It's therefore not patentable.  The A+B patent, if it was granted, is invalid.

Comment: @user133469 First to Invent is followed literally nowhere anymore since 2013.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What the discussion has missed is that how elements are interconnected and interrelated is itself an element. If A and B are things, some C must define their interrelationships.

Image a 4-wheel car exists and what everyone knows is that to be stable a car needs 4 wheels in a rectangular arrangement.

Someone invents a 3-wheel car by realizing stabilization can be achieved by only one rear wheel if it’s located between the front two.

The four wheel car had three wheels but it isn’t a 3-wheeled car. The claim for the 3 wheeled invention needs to not say a car having 3-wheels. That already exists. But a car balanced as a working 3-wheeled car could be claimed.

So A + B + C + D existed but someone figured out how to make a workable A + B + C and has a patentable invention. The seeming contradiction is solved by noting that the first case was really A,B,C,D and X where X defines the relationship between the first four elements. The new invention has A,B,C and Y. It is novel and not a subset of the prior art.

Answer (score 2):

That depends a bit on how exactly the patents came about and are written

1. If you have A+B+C, everyone can do just A+B without infringing
2. A+B is unlikely to be granted since it's included in A+B+C so there is prior art
3. Someone might be able to patent A+B+NOT_C where "NOT_C" is new the invention. That's still unlikely to get granted, but may happen in rare cases if NOT_C is really non-obvious and everyone has been doing +C since the dawn of time.
4. If that happens you can still keep manufacturing using A+B+C. You would not be able to do A+B without doing C as well.

The most likely outcome here that everyone (including you) will just use A+B with no one owning a patent on it.

Comment: Are you assuming a first-to-file regime? Or a first-to-invent regime?

Comment: @user133469 [First-to-invent is no longer a thing: the US is First to File since 2013!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_to_file_and_first_to_invent) - Technically it's First Inventor to File, but still: whoever files first wins the patent.

Comment: @Trish thank you!

Comment: If your invention used A, B and C because A and B alone didn’t work, then the new patent will be for using A, B, plus some very non-obvious trick to make them work without needing C.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that neither of A, B and C is patentable (because they don’t anything useful on their own), and combining them was not obvious which is why you could get a patent.

A and B together don’t work, at least not if combined in an obvious way, or if combined in the way you did if we left C out. So I can’t get a patent for A and B because it doesn’t work.

But I could get a patent for combining A and B in a new non-obvious way. Your invention is not affected because it doesn’t combine A and B that way. On the other hand, your invention is not prior art assuming A and B each were not patentable.